# why when I create an object of a class on the stack, why it didn't delete after leaving the scoop.?

Tags: c++, memory-management

this is my class

```
class game
{
private:
    vector<stack> stacks_;
public:
    game();
    void solve();

   friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const game& game);
};
```

this is the constructor.

```
game::game()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        stack s;
        stacks_.push_back(s);
    }
    cube blueCube(4,0);
    stacks_[0].push(blueCube);

    cube yellowCube(3,1);
    stacks_[0].push(yellowCube);

    cube redCube(2,2);
    stacks_[0].push(redCube);

    cube blackCube(1,2);
    stacks_[0].push(blackCube);
}
```

in the main function

```
int main()
{
  game g;

  cout<<g<<endl;

}
```

after creating the game class why the vector in the game class still have the object.
I thought all objects that are declared like that `cube blueCube(4,0);`  without new are on the stack and when I leave the constructor all of them will be deleted.
Can anyone explain please ?

Comment: You're pushing a copy of those object which are then owned by the `vector`. Also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the objects weren't destructed?

Comment: what is `stack` ?

Comment: Note that `delete` and `destruct` are two different (though linked) concepts. You are asking about `destruction` and _not_ `delete`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have a `using namespace std;` in your code. [Don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). In the code you posted `vector` can be `std::vector` but it could be also something else. I'll asssume it is `std::vector`. In your code `stack` cannot be `std::stack` (it missing a template argument) so it must be something else.

So lets consider this:

```
{
    stack s;
    stacks_.push_back(s);
}
```

`s` will be destroyed when it leaves the scope. `push_back` stores a copy of `s` in the vector. All fine. The copy is not affected by deleting the original (unless `stack` is broken in a weird way. Not respecting the rule of 3/5/0 would cause issues here).

Assuming `stack` also stores copies of the arguments passed to `push_back`, the same happens as above. There is no problem with the original `cube`s getting destroyed.

To avoid the temporaries and the copying you can use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) which, given arguments for the elements constructor, constructs the elements in place.